# i have a problame whit the loop hear no matter how many times i enter the a correct value if the first value i enter is rong the loop keeps on going

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
while annee not in range (1950,1995):
    annee=input("l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995 ")
    if annee in range (1950,1995) :
        break
a=str(annee)
tuple=(a)
c1=a[slice(2,3)]
c2=a[slice(3,4)]
mois=int(input("veuillez entrer le mois de naissance : "))
while mois not in range (1,13) :
    mois=input("le mois doit étre valide : ")
    if mois in range (1,13) :
        break
```

result:

```
le programme sert à générer des codes d'employés
veuillez entrer l'annee de naissance : 1999
l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995 1950
l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995 1955
l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995 1967
l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see the difference between the call before the loop `mois=int(input("..."))` and in the loop  mois=input("...")`? Integers and strings will never have the same value.

Comment: The input function returns a string, but the range generator consists of integers. This example would result in false: "3" in range(5).   To fix it, just convert the str to int: while int(annee) not in range(1950,1995)

Comment: What is the initial value of the `annee` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the input() to int(input()) inside the loops

```
annee = int(input("Enter a value for annee : "))
while annee not in range (1950,1995):
    annee=int(input("l'annee doit étre entre 1950 et 1995 "))
    if annee in range (1950,1995) :
        break
a=str(annee)
tuple=(a)
c1=a[slice(2,3)]
c2=a[slice(3,4)]
mois=int(input("veuillez entrer le mois de naissance : "))
while mois not in range (1,13) :
    mois=int(input("le mois doit étre valide : "))
    if mois in range (1,13) :
        break
```

if you use just input() the value you get is in string form and hence the range() function will not work on it. That is why we have to take the input as int for it to work as intended.